# Кастомный плеер

Tags: java, android, videoview, android-mediaplayer

Возникла необходимость создать свой кастомный плеер, с котроллером, который мог бы управлять изменением текущей точкой проигрывания. Однако, основные методы `VideoView`, такие как `.getCurrentPosition()`, `seekTo(millis)` и т.д. работают только в методе жизненого цикла медиаплеере - `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)`.
Мне необходимо добиться того, чтобы я мог перематывать видео из любой точки кода, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте вот тут почитать: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16723377/3212712)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

они работают не только в `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)`, а только **после вызова колбека** `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)`, который означает, что файл (или поток) успешно загрузился и инициализировался плеером